# assign string to dbgrid cell delphi7

Tags: delphi-7, dbgrid

So I am having a dbgrid that is used as a data entry.
Assume I got 4 fields that needed to be filled by user and another field that I need to assign a value into. Look at the picture.
[image]

I connected that dbgrid to query1 through datasource1.
my question is, how did I assign a certain value (ex:abc) to idpay field so that it will be read without user inputing it?
As dbgrid is automatically posted, I need to assign that value on event beforepost. any idea how to do that?
any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: is the column IDPAY an actual field in the table on the database ? If not how did you created it can you post more details please

Answer (score 1):

Does the Query component you use has the AfterInsert event ?
If so than simply do something like this

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1AfterInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSet.FieldByName('IDPAY').AsString := 'ABC';
end;
```

Comment: that field exists in the database. I need that field as identification thus it doesn't need to be put by user. anyway, I need that to be read before it posts anything so that the string I assign will be read and saved to database.any idea how to do that?thanks!

Comment: I need more information about that. Do you mean that IDPAY should be filled automatic but also has to be unique and that you need to know its value before posting to the database ? If that is the case I would use a GUID to fill up this field. The are unique and can be generated by delphi, but they can be a bit slower in your database